# Jenkins doesn't run http-server

Tags: jenkins, npm

I'm using local Jenkins on windows 10.

When I try to start from the job a local http server with npm's http-server package it fails with "http-server is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file".

When running it from my cmd it works. I also tried to install it global from Jenkins.

Any ideas?

Comment: Jenkins has its own path. Try appending the machines node_modules directory to the path in your job before you call the command. If you have Cygwin installed on the machine you can find the location with `which http-server`. In cmder you can use `where http-server`. Don't know about cmd

Comment: See this link to do it in bat: http://superuser.com/questions/412977/how-can-i-which-binary-in-cmd-exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works using the absolute path of the http-server

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\http-server
```